# Whats causing my python 404 checking script to crash / freeze?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically the script is to scrape a large list of urls , go into each url with requests and find all the links on the page and then check each one of them for 404 and save in according csv file.

I use worked on csv as I like to run multiple instances of the script at the same time with a .bat file to get through the list faster.

```
link_pages_checked = []

for i in links_to_search:

    
   
    i = random.choice(links_to_search)

    print("working on ", i)
    
    print("broken links :" , broken_links)

    worked_on = []## Heading ##

    with open('worked_on.csv', 'r', encoding="utf") as f:
        
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        cats = list(reader)
        for c in cats:
            for url in c:
                worked_on.append(url)
    

    if i not in worked_on:

        with open('worked_on.csv','a+' ) as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            writer.writerow([i])

    

        try:

           

            #go to each url in master csv of combined sitemaps
            
            r = requests.get(i)
            if (r.status_code == 404):
                broken_links = broken_links + 1
                with open('broken_links_found.csv','a+' ) as csv_file:
                    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
                    writer.writerow(["BROKEN FROM SITEMAP!!! :",i])
            else:
                data = r.content  # Content of response
                soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

                links_on_page = []
                #grab all links on page
                for alinks in soup.find_all('a'):
                    if (alinks['href'].startswith("http") or alinks['href'].startswith("www.") and (alinks['href'] not in worked_on) and not alinks['href'].endswith(".jpg") and not alinks['href'].endswith(".png") and not alinks['href'].endswith(".pdf") ):
                        alinks_save = alinks['href']
                        links_on_page.append(alinks_save)
                        
                    else:
                        continue
                

                #check each link on page
                
                 #check each link on page

                
                
                for link in links_on_page:

                    try:


                        if link not in link_pages_checked:

                            link_pages_checked.append(link)

                        
                        
                            r2 = requests.get(link)
                            if (r2.status_code == 404):
                                broken_links = broken_links + 1
                                with open('broken_links_found.csv','a+' ) as csv_file:
                                    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
                                    writer.writerow([link,i])
                                    named_tuple = time.localtime() # get struct_time
                                    time_string = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", named_tuple)
                                    print(time_string)
                                    print("broken link found")
                                    continue
                            else:
                                
                                print("Checking links on page: ", i)
                                print("Number of links on page: ", len(links_on_page))
                                print("Checking link: ", link)
                                
                                print("broken links found", broken_links)
                                print("Total links checked from each page:",len(link_pages_checked))
                                
                                print("working on :", len(worked_on), " of ", len(links_to_search))
                                number_worked_on = len(worked_on)
                                number_total_to_search = len(links_to_search)
                                print("Number left to search:",number_total_to_search - number_worked_on)
                                named_tuple = time.localtime() # get struct_time
                                time_string = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", named_tuple)
                                print(time_string)
                                continue
                                
                        elif link in link_pages_checked:
                            print("already searched")
                            continue


                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                        break
                        
              
                  
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    else:
        print("already searched")
```

Problem is the script will run fine but it only runs for about half an hour then seems to pause and the terminal window does not accept the ctrl-c command to end the process , so have to close it down.

Just wondering how I would go about finding out what is going wrong and causing the crashes / freezes

Answer (score 0):

You could put the whole script in a try:, except: block. Then you could just write the Exceptions to a text file:

```
try:
    yourscript
except Exception as e:
    with open("error.txt", "r+") as f:
        f.write(str(e)+"\n")
    f.close()
```